# How to print the elements inside the vector

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to count the number of end points in the below skeletonized image. I'm using a vector here. What i need is to print the vector , not only the count. I tried in many ways. But didn't work. I'm new to open cv, I found the below code from the internet. Could any one please help me to print the vector which this code actually gets. The code is as follows.

```
// get the end points
    // Declare variable to count neighbourhood pixels
    int count, numberOFEndpoints;

    // To store a pixel intensity
    uchar pix;
    numberOFEndpoints = 0;
    // To store the ending co-ordinates
    std::vector<int> coords;

    // For each pixel in our image...
    for (int i = 1; i < CopyofSkeletionize.rows - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < CopyofSkeletionize.cols - 1; j++) {

            // See what the pixel is at this location
            pix = CopyofSkeletionize.at<uchar>(i, j);

            // If not a skeleton point, skip
            if (pix == 0)
                continue;

            // Reset counter
            count = 0;

            // For each pixel in the neighbourhood
            // centered at this skeleton location...
            for (int y = -1; y <= 1; y++) {
                for (int x = -1; x <= 1; x++) {

                    // Get the pixel in the neighbourhood
                    pix = CopyofSkeletionize.at<uchar>(i + y, j + x);


                    // Count if non-zero
                    if (pix != 0)
                        count++;
                }
            }

            // If count is exactly 2, add co-ordinates to vector
            if (count == 2) {
                coords.push_back(i);
                coords.push_back(j);
                numberOFEndpoints = numberOFEndpoints + 1;
            }

        }
    }
     printf("numberOFEndpoints : %d \n", numberOFEndpoints);
```

I used this piece of code as in the internet but it didn't work. for (int i = 0; i < coords.size() / 2; i++)
        cout << " ( "<

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMZtu.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all... You want to store the coordinates in better way. Maybe something like two vectors:

```
std::vector<int> coordx;
std::vector<int> coordy;
```

Then you just print it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < coordx.size(); ++i)
    std::cout << coordx[i] << " x " << coordy[i] << std::endl;
```

---

Alternatively use a [`pair`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/utility/pair/pair/) (might need to `#include <pair>`) or create custom `point` structure:

```
std::vector< std::pair<int, int> > coords;
```

Adding to the coords vector would be something like:

```
coords.push_back(std::make_pair(x, y));
```

Then you just print it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < coords.size(); ++i)
    std::cout << coords[i].first << " x " << coords[i].second << std::endl;
```

---

Secondly... If you insist on using single `vector<int>`, try:

```
int i = 0;
while (i < coord.size())
    std::cout << coords[i++] << " x " << coords[i++] << std::endl;
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I tried with your first option and the last one. But still I don't see the vector results in my command prompt. :( The code is as follows.

Comment: Zero. As there are no end points for the character "8" as  in the image

Comment: OK, then think with me... You have 0 endpoints, yet you want to print their coordinates... right? Now the console screen is empty... why would that be?

Comment: My goodness. Now I got the point. That did not click in to my mind. Thank you. I tried with another one. It worked. :)

Comment: How can I modify this code to find the joints in this image. Can you help me with this.

Comment: UR welcome :] but this is not a discussion forum... mark my answer as correct, if it solved your original issue. If you have another problem, ask separate question.

Comment: Thank you so much for kind consideration. My issue solved and it worked. The answer was right. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
// get the end points
    // Declare variable to count neighbourhood pixels
    int count, numberOFEndpoints;

    // To store a pixel intensity
    uchar pix;
    numberOFEndpoints = 0;
    // To store the ending co-ordinates
    /*std::vector<int> coords;*/
    std::vector<int> coordx;
    std::vector<int> coordy;

    // For each pixel in our image...
    for (int i = 1; i < CopyofSkeletionize.rows - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < CopyofSkeletionize.cols - 1; j++) {

            // See what the pixel is at this location
            pix = CopyofSkeletionize.at<uchar>(i, j);

            // If not a skeleton point, skip
            if (pix == 0)
                continue;

            // Reset counter
            count = 0;

            // For each pixel in the neighbourhood
            // centered at this skeleton location...
            for (int y = -1; y <= 1; y++) {
                for (int x = -1; x <= 1; x++) {

                    // Get the pixel in the neighbourhood
                    pix = CopyofSkeletionize.at<uchar>(i + y, j + x);


                    // Count if non-zero
                    if (pix != 0)
                        count++;
                }
            }

            // If count is exactly 2, add co-ordinates to vector
            if (count == 2) {
                coordx.push_back(i);
                coordy.push_back(j);


                /*numberOFEndpoints = numberOFEndpoints + 1;*/
            }

        }


    }
    for (int i = 0; i < coordx.size(); ++i) 
        std::cout << coordx[i] << " x " << coordy[i] << std::endl;}
```

I don't even get the vector result from this code either

Comment: This will print something out iff `coordx.size() > 0`, meaning that there are some values to be printed...